# No winapi function for setting the size console window?

Tags: c, winapi

I can change the size of console window like this:

```
mode con cols=64 lines=32
```

Though there are many  [api functions for console subsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I could not find any function for setting the size of  console window.

Is it able to set the size of console window without calling

```
system ("mode con cols=64 lines=32");
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Ken White I've tried `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()` before, but that set the size of buffer, not the size of console window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SetConsoleWindowInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleWindowInfo(
  _In_  HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_  BOOL bAbsolute,
  _In_  const SMALL_RECT *lpConsoleWindow
);
```

`hConsoleOutput` is a screen buffer handle returned by [`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).